# Android Layout proplem

Tags: android

I have a layout contain one image and 3 text field

I've tried to align the image to right and text field to left but I've failed

I've used

`android:layout_gravity="right"` for image and left to text but it did not work also I've used `end` and `start` in gravity with no success

this is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listthumb"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:contentDescription="Rss video thumbnail"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listtitle"
            style="@style/listTitle"
            android:maxLines="3"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shortdescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listpubdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="11dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Your inner LinearLayout is missing the orientation attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `<RelativeLayout>` instead of a `<LinearLayout>`

With the RelativeLayout you could place a widget depending on the position of another widget

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) the Relative Layout description

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help, I have not had time to test....

One linear layout should have vertical orientation and contain the 3 text fields.

One linear layout should have horizontal orientation and contain both the above linear layout and the image.

Answer (score 0):

To push two views to the edges of the screen, you can also give each a left/right margin and then put a blank view with weight = 1 in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Please read a bit more on how [layouts work on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and the different types available to you. A LinearLayout will stack the containing Views either Horizontally or Vertically one after the other. A FrameLayout is simply a container and the items within have to position themselves. RelativeLayout allow you to position your views with a relative reference to other views (in your case, you can position your ImageView, and then your 3 TextViews relative to where the ImageView is).

If you can use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout, you should do so, as RelativeLayout is always slower, due to having to perform two passes prior to rendering as it needs to measure each view and then also perform the layouts based on that. You might be looking for something like (pseudo-code):

```
<LinearLayout orientation=horizontal>
    <LinearLayout orientation=vertical>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not described your question well . Check below code if it works .

You just forgot to add orientation in linear layout containing one text view and a Image view .

Add Orientation to Your Linear Layout.